# How to call script on template condition in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a template conditional like this in my Vue template:

```
<div class="search__container">
  <div v-if="!init">
    <spinner/>
  </div>
  <div class="search__content-container" v-else-if="results.length > 0">
    <div class="search__facets-container">
      <menu></menu>
    </div>
    <div class="search__results-container">
      <results></results>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-else class="search__no-results">
    <div v-html="noResultsTxt"></div><br>
    <v-btn href="/" color="white" class="grey--text grey--border search__continue-btn">{{ continueText }}</v-btn>
    <div id="suggested-products"></div>

    // How do I run this here?
    <script>loadSuggestions();</script>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `loadSuggestions()` call is the bit I can't get to work. It should only run if and when the `.search__no-results` div is shown. I'm guessing I may need to create a watcher with the same conditional logic to achieve this, but that seems overly complex given I already of the logic in my template.

Any thoughts on the best pattern to use here?

Comment: Maybe this can work? `<div @click="loadSuggestions()"></div>` I'm not quite sure about it.

Comment: Watcher is definetly the way to go

Answer (score 1):

You can create a component inside the `search__no-results`, then you call the `loadSuggestions()` in the `mounted` or `created` hook.

OR

```
computed() {
  noResult() {
    return this.init && this.results.length <= 0;
  },
},
watch: {
  noResult(noResult) {
    if (noResult) {
      this.loadSuggestions();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cheers, I think you're right that this is the best solution... It's still not great because it requires a new component, and I'd argue one isn't really need here, but it should work.

Comment: Or you can just check `init && results.length <= 0` then `loadSuggestions()` in this component's `mounted()`

Comment: Detailed example has been added.